# Generic way to center images of different sizes

Tags: html, css, center

I got a series of emission to show , and I want to center the image of each
but images can have different sizes and I don't want to deform them

```css
#emission .card_emission_container_circle {
  padding: 30px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#emission .card_emission_circle {
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19) !important;
  text-align: center;
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

#emission .card_emission_circle:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(216, 63, 65, 1), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(216, 63, 65, 1) !important;
}

#emission .card_emission_image_circle img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
}

#emission .card_emission_container_circle a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(37, 39, 51, 0.9);
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

#emission .card_emission_descript_circle {
    border-radius: 10%;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 0.01em 16px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

#emission .card_emission_descript_circle a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(37, 39, 51, 0.9);
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="emission">
  <div class="card_emission_container_circle grid-4 grid-t-6 grid-m-12">
    <a class="ajax" href="./contentEmission.php?chrid=7">

      <div class="card_emission_circle">
        <div class="card_emission_image_circle">
          <img src="https://www.chassimages.com/mag/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/ImageJour-ThomasMeunier-300x160.jpg" alt="Image de l'émission">

        </div>

        <div class="card_emission_descript_circle">
          <p>Description</p>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="card_emission_title_circle">
        <h3>Title</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>


  <div class="card_emission_container_circle grid-4 grid-t-6 grid-m-12">
    <a class="ajax" href="./contentEmission.php?chrid=7">

      <div class="card_emission_circle">
        <div class="card_emission_image_circle">
          <img src="https://www.france.tv/image/carre/300/300/0/9/9/b5b0b7bd-b4ed2457c172bf7c0abd9e904aff7f5f1a0fea5d60eca094df1dd476b0c6a990.jpg" alt="Image de l'émission">

        </div>

        <div class="card_emission_descript_circle">
          <p>Description</p>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="card_emission_title_circle">
        <h3>Title</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The second is good, the first one is incorrect and I would like to center it vertically into its div, the problem is that I need generic solution, which can be applied to all images, good or 'bad' size

Comment: do u need wrapper divs for circle? cause you can give the image border-radius of 50% with no need for a wrapper, and if you want those wrapper then playing with line-height would be a good old cross-browser way.

Comment: use them as background

Comment: @TemaniAfif I cannot, the src of the image comes from a php attributes, I get a list a emission and show them in a loop

Comment: you can :) simply make it inline ;) and you can do it like you do with the src

Comment: @azro no need to switch to background images. A few simple CSS rules is all that's needed. Check the solutions below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It look like you don't have images with same size so can use the images as background...

Also you have used `vertical-align:center` which is invalid property for the `vertical-align`...*[[Reference Link]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)*

Also `vertical-align` works with `display:table-cell` and `display:inline-block`...so no need to use here...

Also I have used **[Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)** `display:flex` in `card_emission_circle` class so that  inner item can take full `width` and `height` of parent just using `flex:1` to the inner item...another approach is use `width:100%` and `height:100%` to the inner item without using flex

***Stack Snippet***

```css
#emission .card_emission_container_circle {
  padding: 30px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#emission .card_emission_circle {
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19) !important;
  text-align: center;
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
}

#emission .card_emission_circle:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(216, 63, 65, 1), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(216, 63, 65, 1) !important;
}

#emission .card_emission_container_circle a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(37, 39, 51, 0.9);
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.card_emission_image_circle {
  flex: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div id="emission">
  <div class="card_emission_container_circle grid-4 grid-t-6 grid-m-12">
    <a class="ajax" href="./contentEmission.php?chrid=22">
      <div class="card_emission_circle">
        <div class="card_emission_image_circle" style="background-image:url(https://www.chassimages.com/mag/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/ImageJour-ThomasMeunier-300x160.jpg)">
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="card_emission_container_circle grid-4 grid-t-6 grid-m-12">
    <a class="ajax" href="./contentEmission.php?chrid=22">
      <div class="card_emission_circle">
        <div class="card_emission_image_circle" style="background-image:url(https://www.france.tv/image/carre/300/300/0/9/9/b5b0b7bd-b4ed2457c172bf7c0abd9e904aff7f5f1a0fea5d60eca094df1dd476b0c6a990.jpg)">
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good, bu I don't want to deform the image

Comment: @azro If you don't want to deform your images I think you will need to use the images having size bigger than `300px` i.e. your circle size...

Comment: It's not deformed^^ just zoomed right, and I didn't see the flex property, can you just add some words in your post explaining about the *flex* used twice in the css ?

Comment: @azro yes your image is zoomed....I have used `flex` in the css once i.e. `display:flex`....the second `flex:1` is for the flex item to take full width and height of the parent...also updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Two options here:

1. Use the `top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);` method
2. Use `flex` with `align-items` - preferred, imo

Here are the methods:

**1.** It will require adding a `height: 100%` to the `#emission .card_emission_image_circle` element though.

Then we can give the `#emission .card_emission_image_circle img` element the `top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%)` treatment.

```
#emission .card_emission_image_circle {
  height: 100%;
}

#emission .card_emission_image_circle img {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

```css
#emission .card_emission_container_circle {
  padding: 30px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#emission .card_emission_circle {
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19) !important;
  text-align: center;
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

#emission .card_emission_circle:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(216, 63, 65, 1), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(216, 63, 65, 1) !important;
}

#emission .card_emission_image_circle {
  height: 100%;
}

#emission .card_emission_image_circle img {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
}

#emission .card_emission_container_circle a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(37, 39, 51, 0.9);
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

#emission .card_emission_descript_circle {
  border-radius: 10%;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 0.01em 16px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

#emission .card_emission_descript_circle a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(37, 39, 51, 0.9);
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="emission">
  <div class="card_emission_container_circle grid-4 grid-t-6 grid-m-12">
    <a class="ajax" href="./contentEmission.php?chrid=7">

      <div class="card_emission_circle">
        <div class="card_emission_image_circle">
          <img src="https://www.chassimages.com/mag/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/ImageJour-ThomasMeunier-300x160.jpg" alt="Image de l'émission">

        </div>

        <div class="card_emission_descript_circle">
          <p>Description</p>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="card_emission_title_circle">
        <h3>Title</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>


  <div class="card_emission_container_circle grid-4 grid-t-6 grid-m-12">
    <a class="ajax" href="./contentEmission.php?chrid=7">

      <div class="card_emission_circle">
        <div class="card_emission_image_circle">
          <img src="https://www.france.tv/image/carre/300/300/0/9/9/b5b0b7bd-b4ed2457c172bf7c0abd9e904aff7f5f1a0fea5d60eca094df1dd476b0c6a990.jpg" alt="Image de l'émission">

        </div>

        <div class="card_emission_descript_circle">
          <p>Description</p>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="card_emission_title_circle">
        <h3>Title</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**2.** This is bit of a simpler change, and only requires adding the following style:

```
#emission .card_emission_image_circle {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```css
#emission .card_emission_container_circle {
  padding: 30px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#emission .card_emission_circle {
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19) !important;
  text-align: center;
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

#emission .card_emission_circle:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(216, 63, 65, 1), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(216, 63, 65, 1) !important;
}

#emission .card_emission_image_circle {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#emission .card_emission_image_circle img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
}

#emission .card_emission_container_circle a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(37, 39, 51, 0.9);
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

#emission .card_emission_descript_circle {
    border-radius: 10%;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 0.01em 16px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

#emission .card_emission_descript_circle a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(37, 39, 51, 0.9);
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="emission">
  <div class="card_emission_container_circle grid-4 grid-t-6 grid-m-12">
    <a class="ajax" href="./contentEmission.php?chrid=7">

      <div class="card_emission_circle">
        <div class="card_emission_image_circle">
          <img src="https://www.chassimages.com/mag/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/ImageJour-ThomasMeunier-300x160.jpg" alt="Image de l'émission">

        </div>

        <div class="card_emission_descript_circle">
          <p>Description</p>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="card_emission_title_circle">
        <h3>Title</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>


  <div class="card_emission_container_circle grid-4 grid-t-6 grid-m-12">
    <a class="ajax" href="./contentEmission.php?chrid=7">

      <div class="card_emission_circle">
        <div class="card_emission_image_circle">
          <img src="https://www.france.tv/image/carre/300/300/0/9/9/b5b0b7bd-b4ed2457c172bf7c0abd9e904aff7f5f1a0fea5d60eca094df1dd476b0c6a990.jpg" alt="Image de l'émission">

        </div>

        <div class="card_emission_descript_circle">
          <p>Description</p>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="card_emission_title_circle">
        <h3>Title</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```